# How to debug blank white screen Ionic 4 running as UWP on Windows 10

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have finally got my Ionic application building for my Windows platform, however when I run it (after building and installing), I briefly see the splash screen and then just a white window.

If I open the project in Visual Studio (2017), and run it in debug, I get the same thing, and see no errors or any sort of logging.

I then create a new blank (tabs) Ionic 4 project, added Windows, built. and again ran this from Visual Studio, and I get exactly he same thing (a white window - it runs fine on Ionic serve).

My question is, how can I work out what is going wrong? I just don't see any errors anywhere?

In the Visual Studio DOM explorer, all I see is the following...

[image]

So, how can I see what is going wrong?

### Update 1

I must admit, when I look at the Cordova project in Visual Studio, I Just cannot see any entry point? Eg when I just create a blank UWP (in Visual Studio), I get a `MainPage.xaml`. I would expect in the Ionic/Cordova project to also see a entry xaml page which would then host the web view that holds the Ionic JS app?

All I see in solution explorer is:

[image]

### Update 2

In both my app, and the new blank app, if I put a an extra `div` into the `index.html`, ie

```
<body>
 <div>Hello</div>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I **do** see the `Hello` string when I launch the app. So `index.html` is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, it may be the same as [answered here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-isnt-working-for-windows-platform/144167/2?u=peterjc).
So as suggested above, go into `src/index.html` and change the  `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`